# table last updated. php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to execute the following mysqli statement:

> SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE  'QUESTIONS'

I want to loop through the result and find and return the value of Update_time.

I have found some examples on the web but can't get them to work within my PHP script.

My other PHP functions follow the following format and I'd like this function to match it.

```
public function getQuestionsSections() {
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,
      "SELECT DISTINCT
          QUESTIONS.SECTION
       FROM QUESTIONS");     

  $this->throwExceptionOnError();

  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $this->throwExceptionOnError();

  $rows = array();
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->SECTION);

  while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
      $rows[] = $row;
      $row = new stdClass();
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,  $row->SECTION);
  }

  mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
  mysqli_close($this->connection);

  return $rows;
}
```

I'd really appreciate some help in writing the php function as I'm not a php programmer.

An answer to the problem is presented here,

[Having trouble displaying last update time of mySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937968/having-trouble-displaying-last-update-time-of-mysql-table)

Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. It would be ideal if we used the mysqli_prepare as above

Comment: Which storage engine u r using ??
For some storage engines, this value(Update_time) is NULL. For example, InnoDB stores multiple tables in its tablespace and the data file timestamp does not apply. For MyISAM, the data file timestamp is used; however, on Windows the timestamp is not updated by updates so the value is inaccurate.

Comment: I think the storage engine is MyISAM. If I run the statement in myPHPAdmin I get the following result:

Comment: Name Engine Version Row_format Rows Avg_row_length Data_length Max_data_length Index_length Data_free Auto_increment Create_time Update_time Check_time Collation Checksum Create_options Comment
QUESTIONS MyISAM 10 Dynamic 1698 482 818516 281474976710655 1024 0 NULL 2012-07-10 17:23:47 2012-07-10 17:23:52 NULL utf8_general_ci NULL

Comment: You raised a question which I never came across

Comment: Don't put query results in the comments, it's unreadable. Edit your initial question and add relevant information there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE  'QUESTIONS'
```

is equivalent

```
 SELECT UPDATE_TIME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'QUESTIONS'
```

.
You need to access the "information_schema" database for getting UPDATE_TIME (not Update_time) .

```
public function getStatus() {

 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","information_schema");
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con ,
      "SELECT UPDATE_TIME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'QUESTIONS'");     

  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

  $rows = array();
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->UPDATE_TIME );

  while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
      $rows[] = $row;
      $row = new stdClass();
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,  $row->UPDATE_TIME );
  }

  mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
  mysqli_close($con);

  return $rows;
 }
```

I hope it will work .

Reference : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3221/how-to-select-from-show-table-status-results